# To detect if the file contains characters other than integers

Tags: c

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{/*Please ignore extra declarations*/
    FILE *fp;
    int integers[100];
    int value;
    int i = -1;
    char *addr1;
    if ((fp = fopen (argv[1], "r")) == NULL)
    {
        printf("cant open");
        return 1;
    }
    while (!feof(fp) && fscanf(fp, "%d", &value) && ++i < 100)
        integers[i] = value;

    fclose (fp);
    int k;
    k = i;

    int arrlen, processes, j, *pint, number;
    float p;
    arrlen = k;

    printf("Size of array is %d\nThe array is:\n", arrlen);
    for(i = 0; i < k; i++)
    {
        printf("%d\t", integers[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I have to read from file into integer array. Also if the file contains any other character apart from integer it should report an error. I was able to do the first part which i have posted above. Please help me with the second part. If the file contains only integers then store it in an array.PS: This is only part of some program. I have to work on the integer array in the program later.

Comment: Little info on how your file is organized.

Comment: Please don't make us ignore extra declarations.  When you create an MCVE ([MCVE]) for putting onto SO, make sure there are no extra declarations.  It is best to report errors on standard error (use `fprintf(stderr, …)` instead of `printf(…)`).  And when you fail to open a file, it is a good idea to report the file name that wasn't opened — then the user doesn't have to guess about which file it is that you're referring to.

Comment: Note that [`while (!feof(file))` is always wrong](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/while-feof-file-is-always-wrong).

Answer (score 3):

After reading the input, your `fscanf` will return 0 if it reads character, which means it wont read until `EOF.`

Use this after `while` but before closing `fp`

```
if(!(feof(fp) || i==100))
{
    printf("Contains character");
    return 1;
}
```